# Indoor trainer suitible for sprinting

Tags: road-bike, training, trainer

Are there any types of indoor trainers that are suitable for training sprints insofar as they allow the rider to tilt the bike to get leverage as one would when sprinting on the road?

Comment: Trainers are boring - there's no cars to contend with!  Ride on the road, or if you're lucky a handy velodrome.   It is wet?  Rule #5!

Comment: @Criggie Word. My intention is for it to be a supplement not a substitute.

Comment: @Criggie sometimes [the roads](http://i.cbc.ca/1.2472947.1387644931!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_620/kingston-ice.jpg) aren't so good for sprinting either.

Comment: @ebrohman - very old thread I know but did you find a solution that allows you to sprint in a realistic fashion indoors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the videos on the [Kurt Kinetic Rock and Roll](https://www.kurtkinetic.com/trainers-products/rock-and-roll-control) you can definitely stand and tilt the bike side to side.  Whether it would handle Andre Greipel in a full out sprint I couldn't say. It's probably one of the better options to look into.

Comment: The Tacx Neo 2t also has a good amount of side to side flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

The only one I can think of that's designed for this is rollers, but even on rollers you don't want to get too excited because it's easy to ride off them.

You can also buy a cheap wind trainer and not bolt it down, because that lets you throw the bike around and the wind trainer just rattles round on the floor. There's some risk you'll roll forward off it, but that's probably no worse than riding off a wind trainer. It's not safe by any means, but it's possible to do that.

Comment: Using a trainer thats not meant to sprint, and then not bolting it down, and then sprinting and tilting/rattling it around by brute force doesn't sound safe at all.  Maybe I'm not reading the answer correctly...is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Rollers. If you ride off them, practice your technique until you don't. It will make you a better rider.

Comment: Good advice but I don't think I'll get the resistance I'm looking for

Comment: Try them. The rolling resistance is far more on rollers than on road.

Comment: @ebrohman we've got rollers at work - there's a row of magnets that can be moved closer and further from the rear of the rear roller which is steel.  This creates a resistance to motion, and the distance from the magnets to the steel governs the difficulty.