# Best long distance padded shorts for tall man

Tags: long-distance, shorts, tall

sorry if this has been asked million times already...

I need an padded shorts that actually work for making my but stand 150km+ (around 95 miles) a day without hurting as hell after 2 days of riding.

**Have in mind that:**

- I do not expect magic, just the best quality
- I am 2 meters tall (that is around 6.6 foot)
- I am willing to pay for this

My last longride was 335km in 2 days and I managed to stand it but it was not a pleassure for my ass, since it really hurted afterwards...

Thank you for help :)

Comment: You're not going to get "buy SuperDuperbrand pants from Xmart" because we don't do product recommendations on this stack.  Sorry.

Comment: Why not? Well I really appreciate any help, even more the help like you wrote in the answer, yet why is it wrong to add some reccomendation to your answer? In terms of, please do all of this wise things and get this superDuper pants also, since they do work to some extent and you can benefit from it...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm voting to close. Product recommendations are off topic on this site. Please read the Help section

Comment: The "no product recommendations" is a hold over from the original 3 (StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser). Product recommendations go out of date quickly for technology related stuff. Personally, I don't think that things go out of date that quickly in bicycles. Things tend to change a lot slower in the bicycle industry. In tech, even the technical questions can go out of date rather quickly. But, those are the rules. No product recommendations. We see a lot of product recommendations anyway, such as when people ask about flats, we say try Gatorskins or Schwalbe Marathon Plus.

Comment: @Kibbee why not raise that in meta?

Comment: @PeteH I think the [product recommendation ](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/)has been discussed on many times on meta.  The general consensus seems to be that we will allow questions and answers as long as they aren't outright "what should I buy" but rather stuff like "I'm looking for a product that fits these my specific needs" and people responding with "here's a product that fit's your needs and here's the reasons why this product is a good solution". Stuff like my [recent response](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36983/) is a good example.

Comment: This question could easily be fixed by changing the question to "What types of characteristics should I look for in shorts for long touring rides, and what products have those characteristics.  Then people would respond with recommendations about which shorts they prefer, and what characteristics about the shorts make them fit for this purpose.  The answers don't become outdated because we still know what characteristics to look for in shorts for long rides, and can Google for what others are using in lieu of the product that's no longer sold.

Comment: @Kibbee I agree that it has been discussed before, but although the site has a nominal policy, it is something which keeps coming up again and again, so there is clearly some discomfort among the community. But I'll retract my vote to close and let's see what happens to this question.

Comment: Hi people, I am happy that this question is not closed since the current 2 answers I got actually provide good pointers. So thank you all for being cool.

Comment: Voting to leave open because its about bike shorts features for tall people, not a product request.  Could be edited to be clearer though.

Answer (score 3):

I assume given the distance, that you're doing this journey on a road and on a road bike?

You'll be pleased to learn that, as Criggie says, your height is pretty much irrelevant.

You will need to decide between shorts and bibshorts (which come up over your shoulders). Many riders prefer bibshorts because they dispense with the line of elastic around your waist, leaving your stomach "unpressured". But it does really boil down to personal preference.

You also need to remember that there's no silver bullet here. Many experienced cyclists will choose a particular brand of clothing because they tried it in the past and it worked for them. And, not all brands of clothing work for all riders.

Having said that, if you are looking for high-end kit and are prepared to pay for it, I would suggest you could do a lot worse than to look at the kit that the professional teams are using. Not the replica kit, but the team issue kit. You'll pay for it - I'm guessing a ballpark of €200 for a pair of bibshorts - but you are at least getting kit that has been designed to be worn for 5-6 hours over a few hundred kilometers.

Alternatively, you could go to a good (online?) cycle shop, and to start looking at the most expensive kit they stock.

It is a bit of a crass argument to say "best == most expensive", but really until you develop a taste where you can say "such-and-such a  brand works well for me", you have to make a punt of some kind.

Comment: That is very helpful! Thanks for the effort, I really appreciate your answer and Criggie also made good points! Now if it is not too much what do you think about this particular category of products of this brand http://www.vermarcsport.com/en/cycling-clothing/eyJyZXN1bHRfcGFnZSI6ImVuXC9jeWNsaW5nLWNsb3RoaW5nIiwiY2F0ZWdvcnk6dGFyZ2V0IjoiMjM5IiwiY2F0ZWdvcnk6cGFkIjoiMjc3In0 my friend sent me that and said that they are making just what you described the pro cycling team clothing... And this LD pad should stands for LongDistance.

Comment: @DušanRadojević I don't have personal experience of Vermarc but I have heard of them as a reputable brand. Have a look within the brand at the variations on offer, the key things as regards comfort will be the quality of the chamois and the stitching. Unfortunately they're also the things that bump the price up! But chamois expecially. In some brands, the chamois have names, so even if a cyclist buys a different "model" of short, they know that they're getting the same chamois inside.

Comment: oh, and if youn can find a shop who stock these, where you can actually go and examine the fabric, there's no substitute.

Answer (score 2):

There's almost nothing height-specific in a pair of biking shorts.

335 km in two days is a lot of riding - 167 km a day is huge!  You're going to be sore after that kind of ride no matter what.

Can you tell us more about the injury?  I'll guess for now based on my experiences.

**Saddle/arse pain**
If your problem is in the bum muscles, then its a weight and saddle issue.  No amount of padding will help if your saddle is too thin or too thick.   Search this site for "sit bone width"

If the saddle checks out, it might be time for a bike fit.  They're not cheap but they do pay for themselves in comfort.   Us lanky types need extra consideration about how the bike fits, and how we fit the bike.  You might benefit from putting a tiny bit more weight on your hands and on your pedals.  Periodically get out of the saddle for a short sprint too, this allows the blood to flow back into the deprived areas.

A short rest every hour is always a good idea.  Eat, 3-5 minutes of standing and you're good.  Even standing over the bike is fine, as long as your posterior is getting a break.

**Chaffing**
I found that the more I biked, the looser my pants got because of weight loss over time, and as the pants aged the elasticity decreased.  Together these add up to baggy pants, which induces chaffing.

- reduce chaffing by applying petroleum jelly (or some specific+costly bum butter) to the areas before your ride.
- If your pants aren't tight, they're too loose, so either take them in or buy new ones.
- No gruds/undies/briefs/jocks/boxers/etc under biking pants/shorts with padding.  Seriously.

**Other**
I bought normal length pants because the waist was right, and they finish about half-way up my shins.  This is not too bad because the ankles are exposed and provide a bit of cooling.  And a place to sunburn as I discovered on one particularly sunny ride.

---

EDIT I just did a 12 hour bike ride yesterday, and my pants were fine.  The Petroleum Jelly did well, so no chaffing the whole way.  My only problem came from sunburned ankles, because I forgot to put sunblock on down there and as I rode, the pant cuffs rode up and socks rode down exposing skin.

Comment: I highly recommend "costly bum butter" over petrojelly.

Comment: Hi Criggie, thanks for really insightful and useful tips!